# Init a `sockaddr` struct with a given IP address in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, objective-c-swift-bridge

I playing around with Apple's [`Reachabilitty`](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) class in Swift.

The web server in my private Wi-Fi runs on `http://10.0.0.1`. To check its reachability I want to use the following function from `Reachability.h` (not the one with hostname):

```
/*!
 * Use to check the reachability of a given IP address.
 */
+ (instancetype)reachabilityWithAddress:(const struct sockaddr *)hostAddress;
```

I `sockaddr` looks accordingly to `socket.h` like this:

```
/*
 * [XSI] Structure used by kernel to store most addresses.
 */
struct sockaddr {
    __uint8_t   sa_len;     /* total length */
    sa_family_t sa_family;  /* [XSI] address family */
    char        sa_data[14];    /* [XSI] addr value (actually larger) */
};
```

How can I create a `sockaddr` struct with th ip address `10.0.0.1` in Swift?

I already read [[here](https://www.sitepoint.com/using-legacy-c-apis-swift/)] something about `UnsafePointer` and `UnsafeMutablePointer` and that C arrays (or is it in this case an Objective-C array?) are represented as tuples in Swift, but I still don't know for sure how to work with them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You create a `sockaddr_in` first:

```
var addr = sockaddr_in()
addr.sin_len = UInt8(MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: addr))
addr.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)

addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("10.0.0.1")
// Alternatively:
inet_pton(AF_INET, "10.0.0.1", &addr.sin_addr)
```

and then "rebind" it to a `sockaddr` pointer, e.g.

```
let reachability = withUnsafePointer(to: &addr, {
    $0.withMemoryRebound(to: sockaddr.self, capacity: 1) {
        SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(kCFAllocatorDefault, $0)
    }
})
```

*Some explanation:*

There are different address types for different address families (such as `struct sockaddr_in` for IPv4, `struct sockaddr_in6` for IPv6). `struct sockaddr` is the “common part”, and many socket functions which take a pointer to a `sockaddr` as parameter.

In C you can simply cast between the pointers:

```
struct sockaddr sin;
// ...
struct sockaddr *addrPtr = (struct sockaddr *)&sin;
```

In Swift that is done more explicitly as “rebinding”.
For more information, see

- [SE-0107 UnsafeRawPointer API](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0107-unsaferawpointer.md)
- [UnsafeRawPointer Migration](https://swift.org/migration-guide-swift3/se-0107-migrate.html)